# Trouble reproducing principal component plots from a paper?

Tags: r, matlab, bioinformatics, pca

I was initially trying to reproduce PCA plots shown in this [paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/prot.24805/pdf) (Figure 1).
[image] The paper uses PCA technique to visualize protein structure conformations in a lower dimension as per [reference 16](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0969212608001494) (Figure 1 - B and C). Each point in the PC plots represents a protein structure in a lower dimensional space. But I have some doubts now, as I am trying to reproduce these plots. So I looked in this [link](http://thegrantlab.org/bio3d/tutorials/structure-analysis) which is a R library called bio3d from the authors of reference-16. Each pdb files has `{X Y Z}` coordinate positions in their pdb files. After aligning the regions among proteins you take these data for PCA. I am trying to reproduce the results which bio3d toolbox example page has but using MATLAB (since I am not familiar with R). But I am unable to get the plot as in FIGURE-9 in the [bio3d link](http://thegrantlab.org/bio3d/tutorials/structure-analysis).
[image]

Can someone help me to reproduce these figures? I have my matlab script and 6 structures prepared as in the webpage uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B33k4xwdnAxeT1VBeEJrQmp3aEk). The script will help you to load data only although I have made some attempt from my side.

---

**UPDATE 1** : In short, my question is:

***Can someone advice me how to prepare the covariance matrix from the 6 structures with their coordinates for this particular problem, so that I can do PCA on it?***

**UPDATE 2** : I have initially mistakenly shared non-aligned pdb strucutre files in the google drive. I have correctly uploaded it.

Comment: This appears to be quite off-topic as a request for MATLAB code. Please see advice in the Help Center on software-specific questions. If your code contains a reproducible example, then suitably reworded it could be suitable for Stack Overflow. I haven't tried to evaluate whether it is.

Comment: @NickCox : I will rephrase the question asking the way to prepare covariance matrix?

Comment: Still sounds software-specific to me; we would be happy to hear otherwise.

Comment: @NickCox : Please suggest the changes, I will do so. I am not asking anymore about MATLAB or R although the original question is.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand how "prepare the covariance matrix" is an on-topic question here as it seems you're still requiring people to run MATLAB or read MATLAB code. If somebody else understands what you want and can understand that it's on-topic, then fine. Also, as a general but fundamental principle here, questions should be self-contained and not require reading of external documents to be fully understood. Supporting references are fine, but not a reading list or study list.

Comment: Also, please cut out the original stuff that is no longer relevant. People do not want read your question and then be told at the end that most is no longer relevant.

Comment: I will edit. Please give me some time.

Comment: @NickCox I would like to port this question to stackoverflow. I don't if it can be done. :(

Comment: There is an answer from a respected user, so see if it is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the question:

> **After aligning the regions among proteins** you take these data for PCA. (Emphasis added).

You do not seem to have aligned the regions among the proteins first.

This application of PCA to protein structures starts with a set of similar proteins whose 3-dimensional structures have been determined, perhaps under different conditions of biological interest. For example, the proteins may have been bound to specific small molecules that regulate their structure and function. The idea is that most of the structure of these proteins will agree closely under these different conditions, while the portions of the proteins that are most important for function will be different. Those most important portions of the proteins thus may show variance in 3-dimensional positions among the set of structures, and clusters in principal components (as in part C of the first figure in this question) illustrate which particular combinations of proteins and experimental conditions are similar to each other in terms of these differences in 3-dimensional structure.

The {X,Y,Z} coordinates of the atoms in the proteins, however, may have different systematic orientations in space among the set of protein structures, as the coordinate system in any one case is based on details of the x-ray crystallography or other methods used to determine the structures. So the first step is to rotate the individual protein structures so that all protein structures align as closely as possible to start. Then variances are calculated around those closely aligned (after rotation) 3-dimensional structures. Otherwise, most of the variance in {X,Y,Z} space will represent the differences in systematic orientation among the crystallography sessions.

As with all R packages, [`bio3d`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=bio3d) has publicly available source code. The `pdbfit()` function includes 2 important pre-processings before PCA. It tries to account for gaps in structures with a `gap.inspect()` function, and then it rotates the protein structures in 3 dimensions for best overall alignment with a `fit.xyz()` function. Only then does it proceed to PCA.

You certainly could try to reproduce those pre-processing functionalities in MATLAB, but in this case it might be simplest to learn enough R to take advantage of what is already provided in this extensive package.

Comment: Sorry about the alignment issue. I was supposing to do it at preprossing step in my matlab code. But if the align and account for gaps, can you say how to prepare the Covariance matrix?

Comment: I could learn R. But aleast for now I conceptually wanted to know how to do PCA. In those papers it is said cov matrix is having size N x N. But that is the point of confusion since the PCs in the plot is the number of structures but not N

Comment: You can't have more principal components than the smallest dimension of the matrix, which here is the number of protein structures. Your approach seems OK on its face (although I don't know why you are trying to analyze the temperature factors in your code, which aren't relevant here). I would suggest downloading the source code for `bio3d` and look at the `pca.xyz.R` function therein to see how those authors do it. R syntax isn't that difficult to follow, once you recognize that the `<-` operator assigns the value on the right to the variable on the left.

Comment: I tried to follow the source code. I didn't understand it. But I was playing around with script. that's why you saw temp factor in my code. If not temp factor how should I consider from xyz values to get a 6 by N matrix? 6 is the number of proteins

Comment: In terms of the covariance matrix having size N x N (N, number of atoms), it will have at most P (number of protein structures) non-zero singular values (outside of numerical approximation errors) as it is based on an underlying N x P matrix, with P <  N. So the overall dimension of the covariance matrix isn't the issue, just the number of linearly independent rows/columns.

Comment: I am sorry to trouble you again. I don't understand what you said. Let me try to understand the source code.

Comment: As best as I can tell from the code in`bio3d`, the "xyz" format for the atomic positions actually has 3N (N, number of atoms) columns, with the first three columns the x, y, and z positions for the first atom, the next 3 columns the x, y, and z positions for the second atom, and so on. You then have one row for each of protein structures, a P x 3N matrix (P = 6 in your case), on which to do PCA. Still, only P principal components are possible. So I was wrong in saying in a previous comment that your initial "approach is OK."

Comment: I will try this today ans see if I get something similar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53840/discussion-between-dexterdev-and-edm).

Comment: I have uploaded the correct aligned pdbs and tried doing PCA from covariance matrix (P by 3N coordinate matrix). No success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136065/discussion-between-dexterdev-and-edm).